# Separate column values by backslash pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = {'id': [1,1,1,2,2],
        'value': ['red','red\blue','yellow','oak','oak\wood']
}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['id','value'])
```

What I want is:

```
id value   count
1  red     2
1  blue    1
1  yellow  1
2  oak     2
2  wood    1
```

If it's other delimiters like `;` and `/` i can do:

```
df1 = (df.assign(value = df['value'].str.split(';|/'))
         .explode('value')
         .groupby(['id','value'], sort=False)
         .size()
         .reset_index(name='count'))
```

But when it's backslash `\` it doesn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: escape it `\\\` or use raw string ?

Comment: try: `.split.("\\")`

Comment: When you define `data` you also need the `"\\"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **replace** all non-alphanumeric characters from your value and then do a split

```
df1 = (df.assign(value = df['value'].replace({r'\W': ' '}, regex=True).str.split())
     .explode('value')
     .groupby(['id','value'], sort=False)
     .size()
     .reset_index(name='count'))
```

**NOTE**: This will fail if there are other symbols that are not needed for value split.